# jQuery callback executes only to some extent

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

```
$.get("devBlog/index.php", function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        $("#main").empty();
        alert("alert shows up");
        $("#main").append(data); // .html(data) - same result
        alert("alert doesn't show up");
    });
```

above callback function won't execute anything after .append(data) or .html(data) methods

```
    $('#main').load("devBlog/index.php", function() {
    alert("alert doesn't show up");
    });
```

this callback won't work at all.
why? is it because `data` contains at the end `</html>`?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it work!

For unknown reasons, it was the jQuery version.
Switching back from hosted `jquery-latest.js` to local `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` made a difference.

Comment: Have you found out why this was the case?  Could be something to do with the way HTML is parsed by jQuery, when you are using `.append(data)` where data is unparsed HTML.  See [jQuery(htmlString) versus jQuery(selectorString)](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring) and use [`jquery.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/).